# Reduce Contract Size?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I am trying to reduce my contract size by keeping all the codes that has the calculations for the staking in another contract.

My question is, is it good to have Public Library where I have the codes for the calculations or should I use normal contract or delegate call to call another contract which has all the calculations?

Comment: I don't think there's a recommendation for that specific case. It should be fine if it works and doesn't introduce security issues .